Is there an way to model random effects in a design that is typically analyzed by the McNemar test?
My question is: if in a study with paired binary response data (where McNemar test is often used) we can use the exact binomial test to test the odds ratio, is it possible to model the same odds ratio using a GLMM (and take advantage of modeling random effects etc. in this GLMM)?
Essentially I came to this question after reading Fay, 2020: Exact McNemar's Test and Matching Confidence
Intervals.  They begin with this:

Considering paired binary response data. For example, suppose you have twins randomized to two treatment groups (Test and Control) then tested on a binary outcome (pass or fail). There are 4 possible outcomes for each pair: (a) both twins fail, (b) the twin in the control group fails and the one in the test group passes, (c) the twin on the test group fails and the one in the control group passes, or (d) both twins pass. Here is a table where the of the number of sets of twins falling in each of the four categories are denoted a,b,c and d:





Test: Fail
Test: Pass




Control: Fail
a
b


Control: Pass
c
d



Then the author explains why the hypothesis tested by McNemar can be slightly modified and test using the exact binomial test, starting with this statement:

After conditioning on the total number of discordant pairs, $b + c$, we can treat the problem as $B ∼ Binomial(b + c, θ)$, where $B$ is the random variable associated with $b$.

Based on this statement, they go on to show that the exact binomial test can be used to in this setting of paired binary response data to determine whether the odds ratio is equal to 1, where $\theta=\frac{b}{b+c}$ and
$$ Odds Ratio = \phi = \frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$$
Later, in Appendix A (page 4), the author states that:

Suppose we have a logistic model with the log odds modeled as:

$$\log\left(\frac{\pi_{ij}}{1-\pi_{ij}}\right)=\mu_i+group*\beta$$
where:

$group$ is an indicator function that is 0 for the control group and 1 for the test  group.
$\mu_i$ is a random twin effect.
$\pi_{ij} = P[Y_{ij} = 1]$, and $Y_{ij}$ is the $j^{th}$ binary response from the $i^{th}$ pair

Importantly they state that:

Under this model, $\phi=\exp(\beta)$

Given this statement, the odds ratio $\phi=\exp(\beta)$, does that suggest the use of a GLMM to estimate the odds ratio and test for its significance?
If yes, what are the pros and cons?
